# Special methods and tricks in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please tell me your favorite trick and tips to me.
I want to collect so much knowledge as I can.
And I think it's the best way to hear it from experts and amateur developers.

***1. HTML FORM Tag + Attribute "multipart/form-data" and HttpPostedFileBase***

I cloud tell you something about html form tag.
If you use form tag in MasterPage of your MVC project. And you need in one only View one extra attribute for Image Uload like: "multipart/form-data". Be carefull, look at your Code-Source, because you could have 2 Form tags and your parameter of type HttpPostedFileBase can always  be null.
I solved it so: Activated "multipart/form-data" in form just if this View will called.
I did it in codebehind and I know it is not nice solution.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
}
```

Comment: It would be great to start providing your own favorites already in the first place to attract people sharing stuff too.

Comment: Voting to close, this question has no "correct" answer. Should be Community Wiki at least.

Comment: This is a duplicate question of [ASP.NET MVC Best Practices, Tips and Tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709429/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-tips-and-tricks). You can join mentioned community wiki to learn more...

Comment: hm.. you know iam very fresh in mvc, i have not many idea what is my secret weapon. i could just tell one appear with a forms...

Comment: There aren't any secret weapons. You power is your mind.

Comment: @Developer Art : that means I'm doomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Html.Serialize](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) helper method to persist view models between pages and of course [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thank you! it nice to share knowledge